# Writing an IntelliJ plugin that adds HTTP links inside Java source files

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ide, intellij-plugin

I'd like to develop a plugin that transforms certain patterns into clickable web links.

**What plugin type is suitable for this?**

I saw the [Annotator](http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/tutorials/custom_language_support/annotator.html) example, but can its API be used to add a link?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `com.intellij.execution.impl.EditorHyperlinkSupport`,

Also this method [`com.intellij.execution.impl.EditorHyperlinkSupport#createHyperlink(int, int, com.intellij.openapi.editor.markup.TextAttributes, com.intellij.execution.filters.HyperlinkInfo)`](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/fd6a75fa5faa21037591625bb2cb6c301a3ff930/platform/platform-impl/src/com/intellij/execution/impl/EditorHyperlinkSupport.java#L213-L220)  for add links.